# Guava eventBus is reporting "missing event handler" on unregister

Tags: guava, event-bus

I'm getting the following error from Guava eventBus when attempting to unregister a handler.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing event handler for an annotated method. Is [DerivedClass] registered?" at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.unregister(EventBus.java:227)
```

There is an identical question already answered, but the root cause was a client coding error.
In my case, I'm doing everything very simply, and yet still running into the issue.

The client code is an Apache Camel Processor bean, which is running with multiple threads (only 2 in this case). Although eventBus is designed to be thread-safe, the error has only surfaced at time of high traffic, and has only been raised a few times after 1000s of invocations.

The handler instance just stores the Camel Exchange, and if the construction failed, we would fail fast.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    MyHandler evHandler = new MyHandler(exchange);
    eventBus.register(evHandler);

    try {
        doStuff(exchange);
    }
    catch (Foo bar) {
        // stuff
    }
    finally {
        eventBus.unregister(evHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the `EventBus` source code, it seems that Guava 14 onwards does sufficient locking to avoid this problem, whereas Guava 13 and below does not do any locking. Can you use a newer version of Guava?

(It's clear from the error message that you're not on the latest Guava, as Guava 16 onwards calls handlers "subscribers" instead.)